# Auto resizing image banner to fit a div conatiner

Tags: html, css

I have a banner which I want to add to my simple website , here is what I have so far

> HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-12 main-banner">
          <a href="https://www.google.com">
            <img src="images/Test_09-17.png"></a>
      </div>
```

> CSS

```
img{
    width: 100%;
    object-fit:contain;
}
```

I want the image to fit with the div, unfortunately right now i have little space left and right side.

> Check the image:
>   [image]

***Question***

> ***What is wrong with my code?***

Comment: Can you please provide a live example?

Comment: I solved the problem its was about padding with my div which holds the image main -banner set padding zero its okay now

Comment: That doesn't mean you shouldn't provide an example we can look at. That's why I've downvoted your question.

Comment: I thought there is no need because some one pointed  out the problem and he was right , thanks for trying to help, thanks also for downvoting

Comment: Yes, you received a decent answer, but it was a shot in the dark. It doesn't mean your question was well-formed.

Comment: As a side note, you _can_ improve the question and I'll remove my downvote. That's entirely up to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is padding on your image. (Based on the green to the right and left of your image.). Did you check the computed padding on the image element in your browser?

Without being able to see the HTML and CSS for the page I cannot be certain though.

**Solution:**
There was default padding either from the browser or other code. Setting the padding to 0 resolved the issue.

Comment: i dont have any pdding at all just few lines of code

Comment: Did you check the computed padding? The browser could be adding some by default.

Alternatively, try just setting the padding for that image to 0.

Comment: you were right I needed to add padding in my class which hold the image main-banner padding 0 its done. thanks for pointing out

Comment: I'm glad to help.